# D3: Using node attribute for links instead of index in array

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm a D3.js beginner working on a network visualization, and I can't figure out how to properly specify my links for the force layout.  The problem is that by default, d3 interprets the "source" and "target" of the links to be the indices of the nodes in the "nodes" array.  However, in my data, the source and target refer to the id numbers of the nodes, which I've stored in a node attribute.  How do I get the links to point to `node.id` instead of `node.index`?  Here is where I guess I should do it:

```
var nodes = data.nodes;
var edges = data.edges;
var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(edges)
            .size([w, h])
            .linkDistance(80)
            .charge(-500)
            .gravity(0.2)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();
```

... but I'm not sure if I should be modifiying the `.nodes()` part or the `.links()` part.  I tried adding this just before it:

```
var nodes = data.nodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].index = nodes[i].id;
    console.log(i + " " + nodes[i].index + " " + nodes[i].id);
}
```

... but the `index` attribute just gets overwritten when I create the force.

I read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/LWuhBeEipz4/0kZIojCYvhIJ) question, but the only answer there seems like a bit of a hack.  They also mention "data keys", but I can't find much on those, and I don't know how I would incorporate them, since I'm not actually using the `enter()` function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think that you can force D3 to use the attribute `node.id` as index, but you can process the links to have the right references:

```
var edges = [];

data.edges.forEach(function(e) { 
    // Get the source and target nodes
    var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source; })[0],
        targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.target; })[0];

    // Add the edge to the array
    edges.push({source: sourceNode, target: targetNode});
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(edges)
    // the rest of your code here
    .start();
```

The force layout overwrite the index if you set it, but will keep the references for the source and target of each node in the links.

Comment: This didn't work... what do you mean by "Assume that the key in the nodes object is the id"?  Isn't `data.nodes[]` just accessing the nodes by array index, when I should be doing it by id somehow?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I made a wrong assumption about your data structure. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks, that works!  I also had a `type` attribute for the edges, so I had to add that when I pushed each edge, i.e. `edges.push({source: sourceNode, target: targetNode, type: e.type})`

Comment: What is being returned by `data.nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source; })[0]`? A reference to an object in the original nodes array? Shouldn't you only be able to specify references to nodes existing in the force layout graph? I.e., it seems weird that `sourceNode` and `targetNode` can be objects in the following line: `edges.push({source: sourceNode, target: targetNode});`

Comment: Oh, I guess this is possible because eventually the DOM elements are simply bound to the very same node objects within the nodes array. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the node property to use as the identifier by using the nodeId function on the sankey graph e.g:

```
var sankey = d3Sankey.sankey()
  .nodeWidth(15)
  .nodePadding(10)
  .nodeId(d => d.id)
  .extent([[1, 1], [width - 1, height - 6]]);
```