# D3 force layout: How to index data by its ID instead of its index in "nodes" array

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am playing with D3 force layout. In force layout, you have to give "links" and "nodes" in order to make the force graph. D3 interprets the "source" and "target" of the links to be the index of the nodes in the "nodes" array. My question is: How to index data by its ID in "nodes" attributes instead of its index in "nodes" array?
Here is my Json file:

```
{
    "nodes":
    [
        {"name": "A", "ID": 10},
        {"name": "B", "ID": 20},
        {"name": "C", "ID": 30},
        {"name": "D", "ID": 40}
    ],
    "links":
    [
        {"source": 10, "target": 20},
        {"source": 20, "target": 30},
        {"source": 30, "target": 40}
    ]
}
```

I know it has been asked here:
[D3: Using node attribute for links instead of index in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824308/d3-using-node-attribute-for-links-instead-of-index-in-array)

But the solution is not what I want. Because recently I have seen some people doing the special indexing just by passing a simple key funciton:

http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/

```
node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(curNodesData, (d) -> d.id)


link = linksG.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(curLinksData, (d) -> "#{d.source.id}_#{d.target.id}")
```

The problem is I do not understand the meaning of "#{d.source.id}_#{d.target.id}".

Would some like to explain it a little bit?

OK. The above is written in coffescript. When I tried to convert it to regular D3 javascript, the following cannot work:

```
 node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(curNodesData,function(d) {return d.ID;})


    link = linksG.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(curLinksData, function(d) {return "#{d.source.id}_#{d.target.id}";})
```

Cannot work as expected either:

```
link = linksG.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(curLinksData, function(d) {return d.source.id+"_"+d.target.id;})
```

Thanks
Derek

Comment: There are two different things going on here -- first, the resolving of the links and then the matching of the data to DOM elements. If I understand your question correctly, you're concerned with the former. You can in your code replace the ID of the node in the links with a reference to the respective node object -- this is what D3 does internally when you specify an ID. This allows you to resolve the IDs in any way you like.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, could you speak a little more on "eplace the ID of the node in the links with a reference to the respective node object"? Could you show it with my example? Thanks.

Comment: This is what's done in the answer you've linked to -- instead of putting in the number for the node, you put in the actual node itself.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, now I can understand this part. But how to do it in regular D3 javascript. Please see my update. I tried {return d.source.id + "_" + d.target.id;}, the graph can be shown but the two ends of link is still indexed by array index instead of ID attribute.

Comment: What you're doing there is the data matching, which is completely separate to resolving the links. You need code before that which iterates through the links and replaces the node IDs, something like `links.forEach(function(d) { d.source = findNodeWithId(d.source); d.target = findNodeWithId(d.target); })`.

Comment: Instead of using id, try this `link = linksG.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(curLinksData, function(d) {return d.source+"_"+d.target;})`. The point is to provide a unique string identifier, in this case ''10_20", "20_30" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This part is creating a unique id to be used when binding the data to the DOM objects.

```
(d) -> "#{d.source.id}_#{d.target.id}
```

I think this code would be equivalent without the lambda expression -

```
node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(curNodesData, function(d) { return d.source.id + _ + d.target.id; });
```

Comment: I tried {return d.source.id + "_" + d.target.id;}, the graph can be shown but the two ends of link is still indexed by array index instead of ID attribute.